# MySQL/JPA Field doesn't have a default values error, even though the field is in a different class in the class hierarchy

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am using JPA and have a class hierarchy as shown below.

```
    @Entity
    public class Stage {
        @Id
        @Column(name="ID")
        @GeneratedValue(generator = "Stage_IDGenerator", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
        private long id;

        @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
        @Basic(optional=false)
        private StageStatus status;
    }

    @Entity
    @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
    public class TravelStage extends Stage {
        @Basic(optional=false)
        @Column(nullable = false)
        private String source;

        @Basic(optional=false)
        @Column(nullable = false)
        private String destination;
    }

    @Entity
    @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
    public class WorkStage extends Stage {
        @Basic(optional=false)
        @Column(nullable = false)
        private String workPlace;
    }
```

When I create and try and save a 'WorkStage' entity using the following code

```
    WorkStage ws = new WorkStage();
    ws.setStatus(StageStatus.OPEN);
    ws.setWorkPlace("POSTCODE");
    workStageRepository.save(ws);
```

I am getting an error

```
    SQL Error: 1364, SQLState: HY000
    Field 'destination' doesn't have a default value
```

**Why is this happening? the field destination is not in the WorkStage entity. How do I correct this?**

Answer (score 1):

**Field 'destination' doesn't have a default value**

This indicated that your field destination has constrain as NOT NULL and you are trying to save the entity without providing the value for *destination*.

**Solution**

**1. Allow null value for field** `@Column(nullable = true)` 
**2. Provide default value to destination**

Comment: I understand that, but, i am not trying to save the entity TravelStage, I am trying to save WorkStage, which does not have the field 'destination', then why do i get this error?

Comment: @Aj you may need to look https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-inheritance

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution on internet, it works to me

because I have many changes in my model, the solution is drop that table or database and run application to for hibernate to create new db or table